# JQuery: pазбить контент на блоки

Tags: jquery, json, html, foreach

Есть скрипт который обращается в обработчик (POST) за контентом, обработчик отдает данный в виде массива JSON, его нужно распределить на 5 блоков.

Пример того что нужно получить:

```
<li style="float: left">
    <ul>
        <li>ссылка в первом блоке</li>
        <li>ссылка в первом блоке</li>
        <li>ссылка в первом блоке</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li style="float: left">
    <ul>
        <li>ссылка в первом блоке</li>
        <li>ссылка в первом блоке</li>
        <li>ссылка в первом блоке</li>
    </ul>
</li>
........... и так еще 3 блока
```

Получаю контент так

```
$(".load").on('click', function() {
        var type = $(".load")
            , html = '';

        type.attr("disabled", "disabled");

        $.ajax({
            url: base + "load/content/",
            method: "POST",
            complete: function() {},
            statusCode: {
                200: function(jsonArray) {
                    var number = Math.floor(jsonArray.length / 5); // получаю 20, т.е. 5 блоков по 20 ссылок в li

                    jsonArray.forEach(function(cell, index) {
                        html += '<li><a href="">Link ' + index + '</a></li>';
                    });

                    type.after(html);

                    type.text("текст")
                        .removeAttr("disabled");
                },
                403: function(jqXHR) {
                    var error = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                    type.text(error.message)
                        .removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Не могу сообразить как правильно разбить все ссылки на блоки, чтобы они имели выше приведенный вид HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно делить индекс блока по модулю на число эллементов в блоке.

Ещё можно сделать так, не много быдлокод но работает. 
(PHP)

```
        $countToStart = 0;
        for ($c=0; $c<mysql_num_rows($result); $c++)
        {
                $countToStart++;  
                if($countToStart == 1){
                     echo '<div class="row">';
                }
                echo "link";
                if($countToStart == 3){
                   echo '</div>';
                   $countToStart = 0;
                }
         }
```

Ещё можно в цикле делать выборку по n ссылок из массива, и в начале и в конце каждой итерации открывать\закрывать див соответсвенно.

Comment: тока php тут при чем ?

Comment: Так общая логика такая же, что мешает по быстрому переписать на js?

Comment: ну мало ли, может ТС, *или тот кто будет читать решение в будущем* никогда php не видел.

Comment: "webphp"

Но всё-таки могло быть и такое, каюсь желательно было бы на моём месте привести пример на JS.

Comment: HolyMonkey, ну хоть глаза мне раскрыли =) Сейчас в JS предоставлю вариант

Answer (score 1):

С помощью **HolyMonkey** вопрос решен =)

Может кому то и пригодится на JS
Для цикла **for**

```
var countToStart = 0
    , number = Math.floor(jsonArray.length / 5);

for (var c = 0; c < jsonArray.length; c++)
{
    countToStart++;  
    if(countToStart == 1){
        html += '<li style="float: left"><ul>';
    }
    html += '<li>link</li>';
    if(countToStart == number){
        html += '</ul></li>';
        countToStart = 0;
    }
}
```

Но так как нужно было получить данные из коллекции, тут **for** немного не подходит.

Поэтому пишем цикл **forEach**

```
jsonArray.forEach(function(cell, index) {
    countToStart++;  
    if(countToStart == 1){
        html += '<li style="float: left"><ul>';
    }
    html += '<li><a href="url">' + cell.name + '</a></li>';
    if(countToStart == number){
        html += '</ul></li>';
        countToStart = 0;
    }
});
```